# Delete list of s3 objects using lambda python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i have stored the list of files in json format in the source S3 bucket, and am trying to delete the list of s3 objects in a destination s3 bucket using Lambda python(boto3)

here is the python code i am trying with,

```
import boto3
import json
# Set the source and destination buckets
source_bucket_name = 'source-bucket'
destination_bucket_name = 'destination-bucket'

# Set the file format of the object list
file_format = 'json'

# Set the name of the file containing the object list
file_name = 'object-list.' + file_format

# Set the AWS region
region_name = 'us-east-1'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Create an S3 client
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region_name)

    # Get the object list from the source bucket
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=file_name)
    object_list = response['Body'].read()

    # Parse the object list based on the file format
    if file_format == 'json':
        # Parse the JSON object list
        object_list = json.loads(object_list)
    elif file_format == 'csv':
        # Parse the CSV object list
        object_list = csv.reader(object_list)

    # Delete the specified objects from the destination bucket
    for obj in object_list:
        s3.delete_object(Bucket=destination_bucket_name, Key=obj)
```

I am not getting any error after executing the code. But the file is not getting deleted in destination S3 bucket. can someone guide me on the same

I am trying in AWS Lambda to automate deleting the list of S3 objects in a bucket.

Comment: can you try *print(obj)* inside the for loop. If the object is not there the delete function will not throw an error.

Comment: Can you sprinkle a few `print` statements throughout your code to check if `object_list` is indeed a non-empty list? If nothing is happening the list is probably just empty.

Comment: @The6thSense Assuming permissions are correct, a delete of a non-existing object in S3 will work.

Comment: @AnonCoward exactly, It will not throw an error saying object is not available.

Comment: @Praven:  This will fail when you pass a CSV, that returns a list for each row, so "obj" will be a list with the contents of the row on it.

Comment: @The6thSense: No, it will not.  It will return a successful delete.  It will not fail or throw an error.  If you inspect the return, it will include a HTTP 204, but the AWS SDK considers does not throw an exception for this return code.

Comment: Can you check if the bucket is versioned, Incase it is versioned the delete object will only add delete marker but will not delete it. You will need to delete each version to remove the object completely

Comment: @VikramS Thanks for helping with this. no the bucket is not versioned

Comment: Inside the `for` loop, add `print(object)`. Then look in CloudWatch Logs and verify that the filenames printed seem correct. Let us know what you discover!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein am not getting the filenames :(

Function Logs
START RequestId: 6b726130-3e18-46c8-a4d7-e54a39262566 Version: $LATEST
obj
END RequestId: 6b726130-3e18-46c8-a4d7-e54a39262566

Comment: Have you given your Lambda function an IAM Role with the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy? This policy grants permission for the function to write to CloudWatch Logs. You should grant these permissions to all of your Lambda functions. See: [Lambda execution role - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)